# Disable Application Insights from emitting AI (Internal): 72 message:

Tags: azure-application-insights

I recently added @microsoft/applicationinsights-web (version 2.4.4) for one of my projects. I noticed that the latest version automatically dispatches the following trace :

`AI (Internal): 72 message:"Mozilla/5.0 (en-US) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36"`

How do I disable it? I can't seem to see any config options like `IsTracingDisabled` to disable dispatching traces by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable telemetry sent to help track SDK configuration issues by setting `loggingLevelTelemetry: 0`.

Comment: But that is weird, this message is at most of the "info" level, it's surely not a warning or error. Why is it still dispatched when `loggingLevelTelemetry: 1`?

Comment: @Monsignor I assume it's a bug. It's over a year later and this still is an issue.